# Retrieve ETC balance using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-classic, balances

I'm struggling to retrieve my current ETC balance using geth.

For mining I'm running:

```
ethminer -F http://etc-eu1.nanopool.org:18888/<ADDRESS>/<NAME> -G
```

Syncing the blockchain with geth:

```
geth --rpc
```

The first ~0.2 ETC have been transferred from Nanopool which I can see in the transaction history.

```
geth attach
> eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])
> 0
```

I'm guessing this actually returns the ETH balance and not the ETC balance but I'm lost how to retrieve the latter and subsequently transfer ETC to one of the exchanges.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you test if the account is correct?

Comment: Where did you download your version of Geth from?

Comment: Downloaded through Ubuntu packet manager's ethereum meta package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run an ETC node, and do things like check the balances of ETC accounts locally, you'll need the ETC version of Geth.

**ETC** Geth:
https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/releases

ETH Geth:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases

Comment: WIll I have to re-download the blockchain or can I simply stop the old geth process and restart with the new version of Geth?

Comment: After a certain point it's a completely different chain containing a completely different set of transaction data, so there's no real way to switch between the two halfway through. You'll have to start again from scratch, I'm afraid. (Keep the ETH data you have by copying it somewhere safe. It might be useful in future if you want to use the ETH chain for anything.)

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean, there is no way of actually retrieving the ETC coins I have mined so far?

Comment: Solved it. Downloaded ETC Geth as advised, synced on the ETC chain in a new data directory, copied the account private key file to the new keystore and voilà, the balance shows up.

Comment: Brilliant - glad to hear it :-)